# YAML Liquibase / Log4j configuration files syntax in Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml, log4j, liquibase

I was looking for a way to have YAML files for liquibase or log4j verified in IntelliJ just like how it works for application.yaml for Spring Boot. As I understand I should have a JSON file with schema, and load it through Language&Frameworks/Schemas and DTDs in IDE, but I couldn't find any. Is there another way to have autocompletion/syntax hints in Intellij?

Comment: "but I couldn't find any".  Find any what?  json files or the settings in Intellij.  I believe this is more a intellij syntax issue and not directly related to liquibase.

Comment: I couldn't find any proper schema for Liquibase or Log4j to use it. I'm asking because I could not find any other solution but on the other hand, I could find many people complaining about working with Intellij and YAML configuration files for those two frameworks.